# Remove con jquery o javascript deja el div vacío en vez de eliminarlo

Tags: javascript, jquery

¡Hola!
Estoy intentando eliminar completamente un div generado dinamicamente:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deletePauseBtn', function() {
    var numId = $(this).attr('id').split('');
    numId = numId[numId.length-1];
    var divToDelete = document.getElementById('divPause' + numId);
    divToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(divToDelete);
});
```

Parecía que funcionaba, hasta que me ha dado por añadir muchos divs y eliminarlos y he visto que continúan estando en el código y dejan un espacio en blanco cada uno. Es decir, en vez de eliminarlos por completo parece que sólo elimina los elementos que hay dentro.

He probado de hacer el remove() de jquery pero me ocurre lo mismo.

[image: Divs que en principio han sido eliminados]
[image: Espacio que deja el div al ser eliminado]

**Edit:**
Ya he detectado el error gracias a vuestros comentarios y, en efecto, era cosa mía:
Estaba eliminando el div con la id 'divPause + cont' sin darme cuenta que a la vez generaba un elemento padre que no estaba tratando y es el que quedaba vacío en el código. Despiste gordo mío, ¡Sin duda! >< Gracias por vuestro tiempo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit2:**
La solución más fácil ha sido esta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver el HTML, sin conocer la estructura nos es imposible ver que problema puedes estar teniendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los div que intentas eliminar tienen una clase `"pauseDiv"` no un ID, a esos `"pauseDiv"` debes agregarle un contador para diferenciarlos por ejemplo `"pauseDiv-1"`

Pero si el boton .deletePauseBtn esta contenido en ese div que te lo pone vacio, simplemente con este codigo puedes eliminarlo sin necesidad de contador

```
$('body').on('click', '.deletePauseBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest(".pauseDiv").remove();
});
```

Comment: ¡Gracias a tu comentario me he dado cuenta del error! Yo sabía que había añadido una id a los div... pero resulta que estaba generando un elemento padre con la clase que, como dices, no tenía id y estaba eliminando el div con la id dejando al elemento padre allí.